# It seems that Paint.measureText() function is not correct for all languages

Tags: android, text, measure

I have implemented ellipsize text function that works perfectly correct for English Strings. When applied to some languages as Deutch however strings are not truncated properly. After debuugging I came to conclusion that measureText is not workning properly. Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < valueCount; i++) {
         textWidth = mSelectorWheelPaint.measureText(mOriginalValues[i]);
        if (textWidth > maxStringWidth) {
            float diff = textWidth - maxStringWidth;
            int numlettersToSubstract = Math.round(diff / oneLetterWidth);
            int length = mOriginalValues[i].length();
            mDisplayedValues[i] = mOriginalValues[i].substring(0,
                    (length - 1) - (numlettersToSubstract + 3));
            if (!CustomLocaleUtil.isRTL()) {
                mDisplayedValues[i] = String.format("%s...",
                        mDisplayedValues[i]);
            } else {
                mDisplayedValues[i] = String.format("...%s",
                        mDisplayedValues[i]);
            }
        } else {
            mDisplayedValues[i] = mOriginalValues[i];
        }
```

Comment: I have tried TextUtils.ellipsize() but it makes Strings lesser than desirable width, so they cannot be readed properly.

Comment: I've just helped myself. Now I dont use measureText() but instead:

`final float oneLetterWidth = mSelectorWheelPaint.measureText("a");
textWidth = mOriginalValues[i].length() * oneLetterWidth;`